# I'm Dashing and Sassy

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> When I'm by myself, I'm dashing and sassy: two in one.
>   If you exchange my right for left, then your sticks and stones may hurt my skin.
>   Remove one of my parts and I'll be dependent on you, but you won't mind.
>   Changing my tail can change my appearance; that can be an extra benefit.
>   If I was as plush as a Beanie Baby, I might be wildly attractive.
>   Add a double letter and jostle me about, and I'll annoy you.
>   Switch one of me with its successor and I'll annoy you more.
>   Switch another one of me with its successor and you may stumble backwards.
>   Turn me around, cut off my head, figure me out and be rewarded.
>   Substitute me for an imminent part and I am essentially me inside me.

**What am I?**
**What ten other things did I transform into?**

Comment: Why did you write a riddle about yourself?

Comment: It took you 27 seconds to add that comment. Stalker much? :)

Comment: New questions tab is usually open ;)

Comment: This is seriously hard.... I get the whole thing, but unless I can get one word, I am not getting anywhere.... Well, I mean, the first line is obviously "Rubio" but somehow the other lines don't seem to work after that.

Comment: @stackreader what about the lines where it's talking about annoying us :P

Comment: How do you get Rubio from the first line? Seems like Forklift would fit there better.

Comment: A nice riddle! I can't seem to keep them from rhyming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are

> PERT

and became

> PELT, PET, PERM/PERK, TWERP, PRETTY, PEST, PIRT(TRIP), REP, IMPERTINENT.

Of these

> PRETTY and IMPERTINENT are due to suggestions in comments from MOehm and Hugh Meyers. (PRETTY is (PERT+TY)*, and IMPERTINENT is IMMINENT with one M replaced with PERT.) And TWERP is following a hint from Rubio himself in the comments. W is a *double* letter, don'tcha see?) I was in some doubt about these until confirmed by Rubio in comments :-).

Comment: Very good! Could the last one be some wordplay that involves substituting the m in imminent with pert to get impertinent -- I'm pert in ent?

Comment: That's an extremely clever idea, but the "-ent" doesn't make any sense to me at present if it's right.

Comment: It didn't make sense to me either, but I had hoped that you could figure out how it might fit.

Comment: Clearly you just finagle the word a bit and get Rubio!

Comment: Pert and impertinent can be synonyms, hence pert is inside itself.

Comment: Beanie Babies are made by Ty corporation. "Pert-ty" is a dialect form of "pretty". Perhaps this is the idea.

Comment: Either that or the "wildly" is an anagram indicator.

Comment: A bit of a wild guess. "Strep" is short for "streptococcus" so "streps" might be "streptococci" which could be annoying. I hope it's something better though.

Comment: Hmm, pretty = (PERT+TY)* is, ah, pretty plausible. Though I'm not terribly convinced that adding TY to something should count as making it as plush as a Beanie Baby.

Comment: Hugh's proposals are all very plausible, especially with MOehm's modification. It's almost as if Hugh is good with riddles or something.

Comment: The problem with "pirt (trip)" is that replacing the e with its successor would give you F, making the word "pfrt". You could argue that i is still *a* successor of e, but we already established with pert -> pest that when the puzzle refers to a successor it means the letter immediately following the one being replaced.

Comment: I don't see any problem with "successor" meaning "next letter" in one case and "next vowel" in another. (I also wondered about it meaning "next letter in the word", but that turns out not to have been used.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Good point, didn't think of it being the next sequential vowel.

Comment: Mostly correct. Some random notes: "wildly" is anagrind, as @MOehm suggests (the Beanie Baby thing is admittedly, er, pretty loose.)  S is the successor consonant; I is the successor vowel; hope that didn't trip you up too badly.  Finally, STREPS is wrong. (Hint: what single letter is a double letter?)

Comment: Thanks @Rubio! Answer updated appropriately. The successor-vowel thing didn't trip me up badly. I had been thinking of R->S as "next letter" rather than "next consonant" which still feels more natural to me.